# Reachability Xcode iOS5

Tags: iphone, xcode

i want to add a alter if the user is not connected to the internet and clicks on a webview link.

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Can't connect. Please check your internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

Problem is here:

Void (-) gives error:(!)Invalid argument type 'void' to unary expression

Comment: Is this in a .c file or a .m file?  Is this inside an Objective C @implementation block?  Is all the previous function nesting in the file correct?

Answer (score 0):

Very possibly the problem does not lie with the `-(void)webView:didFailLoadWithError` method itself; rather, it seems you are using it in an incorrect way, i.e.. within an expression that requires a unary operator (e.g., negation, increment, etc.).

In other words, it seems you are trying to use the method's return value somewhere, but there is no return value from that method.

Check the code where you call `-(void)webView:didFailLoadWithError`...

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple you dont have to code in any delegate method for check weather the user is connected to internet,for example the there is a login page for you and the user logs in but network is not connectd ,so we have to give an alert to user that the network is not connectd right?just simply add the

```
if(responce == nil)ie,responce from the url
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Can't connect. Please check your internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

} else you code